# Terminal shows only an empty non-editable cursor in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Something has changed in my VS code that doesn't allow me to type in my Terminal. I'm sure it's a config issue but not sure where to look. This is what I see:
[image]

I tried changing my Python version or shell showing on the terminal but no luck. How can I fix this?

Comment: I assume if you just open the terminal instead of using the "Python: Open Terminal" command it also doesn't work? It would suggest that whatever shell you have set as your default is not finishing its initialization.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that. I've tried changing the default shell to sh, bash, and another but still no luck. How would I explore what's stoping them from initializing?

Comment: I honestly don't know. If using the "Change default shell" command doesn't do it then you may need to open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when learning some PHP. After clicking on every option modifier available, I found that in the bottom Status Bar, there was a "Normal" view on the left.

Right-clicked, and selected "Hide Normal" and the cursor and my ability to write code came back[Image of my VSCode showing VIM cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kO7E.png)

In the end I found that I had the [VIM extension enabled](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) and had not used its variables correctly. Either uninstall the extension or use its [commands](https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/boost-your-coding-fu-with-vscode-and-vim/command-line-mode/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).